# Facebook shareDialog is not setting hashtag with SharePhotoContent

Tags: android, facebook, share

I have a sharedialog that works properly in my app. I need to prefill the hashtag, but the following code isnt working.

```
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                        .setHashtag("#ConnectTheWorld")
                        .build());
                .build();
```

I am getting this error...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first semicolon after

```
.setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                            .setHashtag("#ConnectTheWorld")
                            .build())
```

Use the below code

```
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                            .setHashtag("#ConnectTheWorld")
                            .build())
                    .build();
```